# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, eulers-number-e

I'm currently doing AOPS vol.2 and this problem has stumped me for weeks.

Find $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{3^n}$$ Knowing:$$\sin (x)=\frac{1}{3}$$ $$0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

My Attempt: Using$$\sin(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}$$ and plugging that back into the series but i cant seem to reduce it anymore. The book has not talked about $\ln$ or $\log$ trig, so that will not be useful. But it has discussed Euler's formulas such as $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and the aforementioned $\sin(x)$.

Please answer using no to a little amount of calculus as I've not studied too far into it (Taylor series etc). Your solution will be much appreciated.

Comment: Technically, $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ is a calculus result.

Comment: the book says to take it at trivial so they really had no explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{3^n}=\operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}}{3^n}\right)=\operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{ix}}3\right)^n\right)=\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac1{1-\frac{e^{ix}}3}\right).$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I have no idea what Im means, sorry but the book never discussed it

Comment: @LeonardEuler Imaginary part of.

Comment: Thats the imaginary part. If $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $\operatorname{Im}(a+bi)=b$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but I've never solved a problem like that so I have no idea what your solution means, but thanks it seems interesting and ill revisit your solution in time :)

Comment: @LeonardEuler how do you understand the other solution then????

Comment: @mathworker21 because it doesn't involve the Im part which I'm not familiar in when solving series. Basically, I know a lot of formulas but I don't know many methods, if that makes sense.

Comment: @LeonardEuler so what's wrong with a solution that teaches you a new method? also, you said you didn't know what "Im" meant, so I don't know why you're now saying "which I'm not familiar in *when solving series*".

Comment: What i was saying is i know what Im means (the imaginary part) but i don't know how that could be used in sigma. If it helps you understand im only 15 years old so to me, the imaginary part of sigma makes no sense to me. As to learning new methods, you can see in one of my comments that ill will revisit his solution when I learn what Im mean in TERMS of sums. I hope there are no hard feelings, I did, in fact, forget to "check" his solution, so thats my fault.

Comment: @LeonardEuler The sum of some complex numbers is just a complex number (if it converges), so its imaginary part has the usual meaning. In particular, the sum's imaginary part is the sum of the original complex numbers' imaginary parts.

Comment: @LeonardEuler ok, then you should have said "I don't know what $Im \sum$ means" rather than the vague "I don't know what $Im$ means when solving series". And of course no hard feelings lol. You're in a good place for a 15 year old :)

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks for understanding, it's my fault, I should have clarified. But it's great to learn new things! :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\sin (nx)}{3^n}=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n\ge0}\left[\left(\frac13 e^{ix}\right)^n-\left(\frac13 e^{-ix}\right)^n\right]=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{1-\frac13 e^{ix}}-\frac{1}{1-\frac13 e^{-ix}}\right]\\=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{\frac{10}{3}-2\cos x}=\frac{3\sin x}{2(5-3\cos x)}.$$Using $\sin x=\frac13,\,\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$, the above simplifies to$$\frac{1}{2(5-2\sqrt{2})}=\frac{5+2\sqrt{2}}{34}.$$

Comment: did you mean to put $n≥0$ in the sum?

Comment: @LeonardEuler $\sum_{n\ge0}a_n$ is an alternative notation for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, as in both cases the values of $n$ over which we sum is the non-negative integers.